# options for Audio capture raw data in QT6 C++

Tags: c++, qt, audio, audio-streaming

since QT6 support for Multimedia has been deferred to later this year, what are the alternative library to capture audio from microphone?
I have used OpenCV to make my webcam work, I am looking for alternative library to capture audio and get raw audio buffer (not dump to file) as I need to encode it using our custom compression and send to network.
Im in C++ by the way.

Answer (score 1):

Audio capturing is different for operating systems and some hardwares. In general, I add some together here for different views.

**[WASAPI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/coreaudio/wasapi)** - The Windows Audio Session API (WASAPI) enables client applications to manage the flow of audio data between the application and an audio endpoint device.

**[libsoundio](http://libsound.io/)** - libsoundio is a lightweight abstraction over various sound drivers. It provides a well-documented API that operates consistently regardless of the sound driver it connects to. **MIT** licensed

[**PulseAudio**](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/) - PulseAudio is designed for Linux systems. It has also been ported to Solaris, FreeBSD, NetBSD, MacOS X, Windows 2000 and Windows XP, but we don't currently have maintainers using non-Linux system

**[GStreamer](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/)** - GStreamer is a library for constructing graphs of media-handling components. The applications it supports range from simple Ogg/Vorbis playback, audio/video streaming to complex audio (mixing) and video (non-linear editing) processing. GStreamer is released under the **LGPL**

[**RtAudio**](https://github.com/thestk/rtaudio) - A set of C++ classes that provide a common API for realtime audio input/output across Linux (native ALSA, JACK, PulseAudio and OSS), Macintosh OS X (CoreAudio and JACK), and Windows (DirectSound, ASIO and WASAPI) operating systems. **Similar to the MIT License**

**[PortAudio](http://www.portaudio.com/)** - PortAudio is a free, cross-platform, open-source, audio I/O library.  It lets you write simple audio programs in 'C' or C++ that will compile and run on many platforms including Windows, Macintosh OS X, and Unix (OSS/ALSA). **Compatible with GNU GPL**.

**[JUCE](https://github.com/juce-framework/JUCE)** - JUCE is an open-source cross-platform C++ application framework for desktop and mobile applications, including VST, VST3, AU, AUv3, RTAS and AAX audio plug-ins. The core JUCE modules are permissively licensed under the terms of the **ISC license**. Other modules are covered by a **GPL/Commercial license**.